# fetch() method throwing error, ( Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch) (GET url net::ERR_FAILED)

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, google-developers-console

`fecth()` method is throwing error in google console. while I test this in firefox dev tool the promise is getting fulfilled status. I don't know what's wrong.
here is my code

```js
fetch('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/mubarakhusain/fakeserver/db').then((response) => {
return response.json();}).then((data) => {
console.log(data);});
```

Comment: I just tried your code in both Firefox 87.0 and Chrome 89.0. It worked just fine, no errors, and it got logged.

Comment: "in google console" What was the page being inspected's origin?

Comment: @Rojo now it's working absolutely I don't understand what was the issue. When my friend checked it on chrome even that time it wasn't working and throwing the same error.

Comment: @viperMubi it might be your server not being able to handle the requests

Comment: Yeah, it's working fine now.